# Listing all recognizable colours in R

Tags: r, colors

I have a somewhat trivial question. I am writing a script that will recognize user input which corresponds to R colours. But to do this I need a character string of all R colours. Is there a way to get this without having to retype everything from a online PDF file cheat sheet? I have tried:

```
demo("colors")
```

But it only shows me the colours graphically. It would be nice to assign them to a variable as a character string.

Thank you!

Comment: use `colors()`.

Comment: Well that was easy! Thank you!